# Difference between X.509 standard and PKCS standard

Tags: pkcs#12, x509

Whats the difference between X.509 standard and PKCS standard and how do they relate?
What I understood after googling is that X.509 defines the main standard for digital certificates and PKCS is just some flavors(extensions such as .p12) of it. But I'm not quite sure whether am I right. Problem is both are considered as standards and that confuses me.

Comment: The way I understand it, X.509 is the encryption standard whereas PKCS is a storage format (envelope) standard.

Comment: The nice thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from ;-)

Comment: Interesting but can some one please give me a little more insight. 
Tnx